# Computing k means and plotting over the scatter plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I want to plot 3 "k means" points in the scatterplot.

```
from pylab import plot,show
from numpy import array
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq

data = array([1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,7,7,7,7,7,7])
plot(data,marker='*',linewidth=0)

centroids,x = kmeans(data,3)
idx,x = vq(data,centroids)

plot(data[idx==0,0],data[idx==0,1],'yellow',
     data[idx==1,0],data[idx==1,1],'yellow',
     data[idx==2,0],data[idx==2,1],'yellow') 

plot(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],'red',markersize=8)
show()
```

What is wrong going with the code above since the following error was yielded:

```
plot(data[idx==0,0],data[idx==0,1],'yellow',
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: `data[idx==0,0]` what are you trying to achieve with it? it's not a python valide syntax

Comment: @Oz123 - `data[idx==0, 0]` is perfectly valid python syntax, and it's a very common idiom in numpy (though it's used elsewhere, as well).

Comment: @JoeKington, I dare to say: can you show a working example ? I'd like to learn something new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax `data[idx==0,0]` is incorrect.

```
>>> data[idx==0,0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Later on, `centroids[:,0]` will also result in `IndexError: too many indices` error, as `centroids` is a 1-d array.

The problem lies in the fact that your data is 1-d, and to plot a scatter plot you need values for 2 coordinates. The following will do:

```
>>> data = data.reshape(9,2) # 2d array of x,y coordinates
>>> data
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 3],
       [7, 7],
       [7, 7],
       [7, 7]])
>>> centroids, x = kmeans(data,3) # clusters in 2d
>>> idx, x = vq(data,centroids)
```

cluster `0` x-cooridinates

```
>>> data[idx==0][:,0]
array([1, 1, 1])
```

cluster `0` y-coordinates

```
>>> data[idx==0][:,1]
array([1, 1, 1])
```